# Cloud Function to Update a Record (value = value + newValue) whenever a value chages in Firebase Databse

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Cloud Functions.

I have a table 'drivers' with having few details.

[image: DB Snapshot]

Now I want to write a Firebase Cloud Function which will

1. trigger whenever the value in 'drivers/{driverId}/history/{rideId}/rating' is set.
2. Update totalRating (drivers/{driverId}/totalRating) value to oldTotalRatingValue + NewTotalRatingValue.

Any help or a reference would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

=============My Approach======================

```
exports.increaseRating = functions.database.ref('/drivers/{driverId}/history/{historyId}/rating')
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    var newRating = snapshot.after.val();
    var oldRating = 0;
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref(`/drivers/${context.params.driverId}/totalRating`);
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      oldRating = snapshot.val();
    });
    console.log(oldRating);
    var finalRating = oldRating + newRating;
    return admin.database().ref(`/drivers/${context.params.driverId}`).update({
        "totalRating": finalRating,
    })
})
```

but my var oldRating doesn't updates to database value.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific question, but you might want to read the Firebase documentation on data structuring as it recommends against the type of data nesting that you have: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data

Comment: If the goal is to observe the history of all drivers for changes, this is not the correct structure.You should break out the history for each driver and store that at a higher level and observe that for changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`Transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#transaction) if you want to update the `totalRanking`, in order to avoid that another instance of the Cloud Function writes to the `totalRanking` location before your new value is successfully written by the current Cloud Function.

The following should work (untested):

```
exports.increaseRating = functions.database.ref('/drivers/{driverId}/history/{historyId}/rating')
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {

        const newRating = snapshot.after.val();

        const totalRatingRef = admin.database().ref(`/drivers/${context.params.driverId}/totalRating`);

        return totalRatingRef.transaction(currentTotalRating => {
            // If /drivers/{driverId}/history/{historyId}/rating has never been set, newRating will be `null`.
            return currentTotalRating + newRating;
        });

    });
```

---

Note that we are returning the Promise returned by the Transaction. More details on this key point in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Cloud Fucntion with Realtime Database trigger `onWrite`. Here is [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for this. The method [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#onwrite) says:

> Event handler that fires every time a Firebase Realtime Database write
> of any kind (creation, update, or delete) occurs.

Function should start more or less like:

```
...
exports.<your function name> = 
    functions.database.ref('drivers/{driverId}/history/{rideId}/rating')
    .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
...
```

When it comes to updating you cloud function is node application so you can use firebase admin sdk in it. Tutorial is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). Just get value and update.

I can see you will need `driverId` for reference. You can get it from trigger wildcard like this `context.params.driverId` (check wildcard is in trigger doc).